# actual_write->WriteLine("insert new line \n");

Tags: visual-c++, file-io, c++-cli

I am coding in Visual c++/CLI and I want to write to a text file and insert a new line or two empty lines.  The problem is that the writing works perfectly but the new line is not inserted even though I wrote `\n`.

if you need any more information about my code I will provide it.

```
actual_write->WriteLine("insert new line  \n");
actual_write->WriteLine("insert new line  \n");
```

The output is:

```
insert new line   
insert new line
```

I want it to be:

```
insert new line 

insert new line
```

Comment: It is \r\n on Windows.  You avoid such dependencies by using Environment::NewLine instead.  Like actual_write->WriteLine("Hello{0}world", Environment::NewLine);

Comment: Or just add an additional `actual_write->WriteLine()` between the two other writes.

Answer (score 0):

On windows \r\n is the line break. It's just console resolves \n to \r\n